# CSS Adjustment of HTML Elements

Tags: php, html, css

I need help with adjusting a certain html element `<div class="content">` with css so that it will be fixed and responsive like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1ZGT.jpg) on that position regardless of screen dimensions and not like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR6Qq.jpg).

I change the width of `#info #head>.content` from `100%` to `82%` but on a smaller screen dimension it overlaps with the cover image.

HTML Code

Snippet

```
<div id="head">
<div class="content">
<div class="uigrid">
<div class="contingo">
<p style="font-size:30px;">Meng Qi Shi Shen</p>
<div class="horizontal-list">
<a href="/anime-list" class="item">Adventure</a>
<a href="/anime-list" class="item">Comedy</a>
<a href="/anime-list" class="item">Drama</a>
<a href="/anime-list" class="item">Historical</a>
<a href="/anime-list" class="item">Romance</a>
<a href="/anime-list" class="item">Shoujo</a>
<div class="type"><span class="sub" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; changegrid()">Sub</span><span class="dub" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; changegrid()">Dub</span></div> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Full php(html) code

```
https://codeshare.io/arj6eA
```

CSS Code

```
https://codeshare.io/GbyP86
```

Comment: Can you setup this code in JsFiddle? It's difficult to setup the code you have provided.
or if it is setup some where live, just share the link

Comment: try to use max-width in your css based on device

Comment: @Ali Sajid I can't seem to set it up on JsFiddle but here is the live link (https://www11.animerhino.com/anime/3968-ashita-e-free-kick)

Comment: @JackSiro I tried doing max-width for `#info #head>.content` css element but its just pushing all the way to the left. check screenshot (https://i.imgur.com/VDQhP0D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use max-width of device to adjust the with you want. Like for instance if the decive is width is 600ps

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #info #head:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 82%;
    height: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px #1b1c1d;
 }
}
```

or like this one when the width of the device is 1000px

```
 @media (max-width: 1000px) {
      #info #head:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 75%;
        height: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px #1b1c1d;
     }
    }
```

for more of this please check here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_templates.asp

Comment: add !important  or continue to do research

Comment: please consider using the keyword important on your css to see if you can override some of the inherited elements